# SVN issue with tag and branches

Tags: svn

I had check out code from tag module from my project by mistake and also had done many changes in tag module. I want to get the same code changes done in tag module to branches module can any one help with these.

Project Structure:

```
^/project
     /tags
     /branches
     /trunk
```

I had check out from tags and done many changes. I need all the changes to the branches module to commit to the svn branches module.

Comment: Please be more specific what you did and what you want to achieve. Provide - for example - the commands you used and/or some sort of (ascii) graphic how your repository looks like

Comment: In SVN every projects will have 3 modules like branches,tags,trunk we need to check out the code from branches and done our development and commit our changes. But I had check out from tags module and done changes when I try to synchronize with repository I am not able to see any previous code in tags module. So, I want to know how can I get all the changes to my branches modules.

Comment: So your structure looks like this: repository --> projectA -> trunk, branches, tags; repository --> projectB -> trunk, branches, tags OR is it repository --> trunk, branches, tags? Which svn commands have you used so far? Please edit the question and add all those informations.

Comment: When you are saying "and done many changes" do you also mean that you already committed your changes or are they only in your working copy?

Comment: they are only in my work copy. when tried to synchronize with repository in tags module I am not able to compare with the older code. Suggest me how can I get the changes to the branches to do further development.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you got at least two options:

1. Commit your changes in the local working copy. The second step than is to merge the changes form ^/project/tags to ^/project/branches (see [Chapter 4](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html) of the SVN Book)
2. Do a checkout of ^/project/branches in another directory. Now copy your modified files from your tag-working copy to the branches-working copy. Now you could commit your branches-working copy. Instead of copying you could also use some merge tool.